Boundary Conditions for Self-Adjoint Laplacian on Weighted $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with Weight $e^{-|x|}
I'm trying to construct a self-adjoint or essentially self-adjoint Laplacian operator ($\Delta = d^2/dx^2$) on the weighted $L^2$ space $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^{-|x|} dx)$. My goal is to define the operator on a dense subspace of compactly supported smooth functions, $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, with appropriate boundary conditions.
The weight function $w(x) = e^{-|x|}$ has a discontinuous derivative at $x = 0$, which complicates the usual integration by parts arguments used to establish symmetry and determine deficiency indices.
I'm particularly interested in the following:

Symmetry: I understand that imposing $f(0) = 0$ is necessary for symmetry. However, due to the discontinuity of $w'(x)$, it seems that an additional condition on the derivative at $x = 0$ is needed. I've considered both $f'(0) = 0$ and $f'(0+) = f'(0-)$, but I'm not sure which (if either) is sufficient to guarantee symmetry on a dense subspace of $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Deficiency Indices: After ensuring symmetry, I want to determine the deficiency indices of the Laplacian on my chosen domain. My ultimate goal is to have trivial deficiency indices $(0, 0)$, indicating essential self-adjointness, or at least identify the self-adjoint extensions if the deficiency indices are non-trivial.

Essential Self-Adjointness or Self-Adjoint Extensions: If the operator is not essentially self-adjoint on the initial domain, I'm interested in understanding what boundary conditions characterize the self-adjoint extensions.


Specific Questions:

What is the minimal set of boundary conditions at $x = 0$ that, when imposed on a suitable dense subspace of $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, ensures the symmetry of the Laplacian with the weight $e^{-|x|}$?

If I impose both $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0+) = f'(0-)$ (or $f'(0) = 0$), are the deficiency indices of the Laplacian guaranteed to be $(0, 0)$ on the resulting domain? If not, what are the deficiency indices, and how can the boundary conditions be modified to potentially achieve essential self-adjointness?

If the deficiency indices are non-trivial, what is the general form of the boundary conditions that characterize the self-adjoint extensions of the Laplacian in this weighted $L^2$ space?


Context:
I've attempted to calculate the deficiency indices by solving the equations $(\Delta^* \pm iI)g = 0$ in the weighted space, where $\Delta^*$ is the adjoint of the Laplacian. However, I'm getting conflicting results depending on whether I start with functions that vanish in a neighborhood of 0 or functions that satisfy $f(0)=f'(0) = 0$. This has led to confusion about the correct approach and the role of the boundary conditions.
Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Consider splitting the real line into two regions and using a single integration-by-parts identity that treats the boundary at zero as an interior interface. Write the inner product of $\Delta f$ and $g$ as the sum of two integrals over $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ with weight $w(x)=e^{-|x|}$. Each partial integration introduces boundary contributions at infinity, which vanish for functions in the weighted space due to exponential decay, and contributions at zero. In the interval $(-\infty,0)$, take $\int_{-\infty}^0 f''(x)\,g(x)\,e^x\,dx$, integrate by parts twice, and do the same for $(0,\infty)$ with weight $e^{-x}$.
The boundary terms at zero combine into expressions involving $f(0)$, $f'(0^\pm)$, $g(0)$, $g'(0^\pm)$. For symmetry, the resulting boundary form
$$\bigl[f'(0^-)g(0^-)-f(0^-)g'(0^-)\bigr]e^0 + \bigl[f'(0^+)g(0^+)-f(0^+)g'(0^+)\bigr]e^0$$
must vanish whenever $f$ and $g$ are in the domain. Imposing $f(0)=0$ eliminates the terms mixing $f(0)$ with $g'(0)$; however, the jump in $w'(x)$ suggests matching the flux across zero to handle the extra term generated by the derivative of the weight. The condition $f'(0^+)=f'(0^-)$ suffices for the boundary form to vanish because it enforces a consistent derivative across the interface when $f(0)=0$.
The equation $(\Delta\pm i)g=0$ in each half-line with exponential weights requires solutions lying in the weighted space while satisfying these interface conditions. General solutions in each half-line behave like linear combinations of decaying exponentials times polynomials in $\pm i$, and the interface condition at zero constrains these combinations. If the only solution that remains in $L^2(\mathbb{R},e^{-|x|}dx)$ when $\Delta^* \pm i$ is applied is the trivial one, the deficiency indices are $(0,0)$, yielding essential self-adjointness. A two-parameter family of boundary conditions describes self-adjoint extensions, typically through a nontrivial linear relationship among $f(0)$, $f'(0^+)$, $f'(0^-)$.
Under the strict conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0^+)=f'(0^-)$, the only square-integrable solutions to $(\Delta\pm i)g=0$ vanish, forcing the deficiency indices to be zero and giving essential self-adjointness on that domain.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
